# 'if' statement sometimes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-sheets

```js
function onNumarator() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Emirler"));

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
  var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emirler").getRange('G1').getValue();

  if (sheet.getRange(row, 6) == null) {

    sheet.getRange(row, 6).setValue(id);
    sheet.getRange('G1').setValue(id + 1);
  } else {};

  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
  sheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue(email);


}
```

G1 is a reference cell, I set value 1 for first form and It increases +1 after every form submittion.

If user doesn't fill out the "ilan ID" (which is located on column F) section on form, it suppose to give a number automaticaly, but the script stop working after a while, I messed up something I guess. It sets the email address but doesn't gives number as I want. I couldn't find the problem.

Comment: And also, the function trigger is set to onFormSubmit

Comment: if `sheet.getRange(row, 6)` is null, how can you call `.setValue` on it? I think you have the test backwards.

Comment: What do you suggest? How should I cahnge the script? Please Help :)

Comment: Not sure, because I don't understand what it's trying to do with that test. I don't know much about Google Spreadsheet, but I guess it will only return `null` if there are no cells in the range. Maybe what you want to do is get the value of the cell, and test `if (sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue() == '')`

Comment: I have also tried this:
if (sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue() == null)

Comment: if (sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue() == "") it works thanky you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct test is:

```
  if (sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue() == "") {
```

You were testing whether there was no cell at all. You need to get the value and see if it's empty.